# Is it possible to make the buyer pay the fee when accepting payments via PayPal?

Tags: paypal

When accepting payments via PayPal is it possible to make the buyer pay the fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possibly by adding the fee %ge to the price of all of your products - you can usually add this on most ecommerce carts at the checkout stage.

I suspect you're looking for the ability to force the user to pay the fee on top of your displayed price though, in which case it's not possible. See the PayPal administrator response here:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Fees-Archive/How-do-I-set-up-my-acoount-so-the-buyer-pays-the-paypal/td-p/131788

> "While individual merchants may work the cost of their payment processor into the overall cost of the items they sell, just as the local grocery store does, the same would apply to PayPal.  Our experience has been that buyers who are asked to pay a fee up front on a transaction, just to make the purchase, will not purchase from a merchant.  This is the same with your local grocery store - if they were to ask their shoppers to pay a transaction fee, business would steadily decline and eventually disappear.  As such, the option to directly pass transaction fees on to the buyer does not exist."